# How to restart the SAS Object Spawner

Tags: sas

In order to be able to export files from SAS to an SFTP site, a SAS admin needs to follow the configurations below:

1. Open the SAS Management Console
2. Expand “Server Manager”
3. Go to SASApp > SASApp Logical Workspace Server > SASApp Workspace
   Server
4. Right click on SASApp Workspace Server and select Properties
5. Go to Options > Advanced Options > Launch properties > Select the
   “Allow XCMD” here
6. Restart the SAS object Spawner

Does anyone know how to do the last step:

> Restart the SAS object spawner ?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, most installs have this as a service.  Open the Services console and restart it.  Otherwise there is a bat file for operating the spawner in the config directory.  On my system it is C:\SAS\Config\Lev1\ObjectSpawner2, but will probably be different on yours.

On Unix/Linux, there will be a shell script in the configuration directory to do this for you.  I don't have a *NIX install to give you exact paths.